# How and when to use the "law of total expectation", a.k.a. "tower property"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I know what it is and how to prove it. However, I am not able to use it for problem solving. I would really appreciate if you can point out some kind of problems where it is usually applied. Thanks.

Comment: It is the go-to trick to use when dealing with compounded sums of random variables when enough independence is present.

Comment: Can you give one example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example

Consider a sequence of iid random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ and a discrete random variable $N$, independent of $\{X_i\}$. Now consider the compound sum
$$
S_N = \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i
$$ 
and find the expected value of it. That is,
$$
E[S_N] = E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i\right].
$$
From here, we will apply the tower property,
$$
E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i\right] = E\left[E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i \;\middle \vert \; N\right]\right] = E\left[  E[N \cdot X_1\mid N]\right],
$$
where we used that the $X_i$'s are iid ($X_i \stackrel d= X_1$ for all $i$) in the last equality. If you are not convinced of the second equality, try to do, informally, the steps with $N = n$ fixed instead of a random variable.

From here on, use that a random variable is measurable to itself, i.e. $E[N\mid N] = N$ and the independence between $X_1$ and $N$, giving $E[X_1\mid N] = E[X_1]$ to finally get
$$
E[S_N] = E\left[  E[N \cdot X_1\mid N]\right] = E[N]E[X_1].
$$

Comment: So, in this case, is N also random variable? Therefore, we first condition on it taking it as constant N and find the inner expected value. Afterwards, we find the expected value of N, right? Thanks.

Comment: The important thing is, in the step above, $N$ is still a random variable but we may treat it heuristically as a constant. Indeed, $E[Z \mid N]$ is a random variable whereas $E[Z\mid N = n]$ is not. [Sokol and Rønn-Nielsen (2013) page 124-127](http://www.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf) may not be a classical reference, but indeed I find they explain it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the case when the entire sample space can be partitioned into a discrete set of events? If yes, here is an example:

Suppose that adult male lions weight an average of 420lb, while adult female lions weight an average of 280lb. Suppose also that adult male lions constitute 20% of each pride, while adult female lions constitute the remaining 80%. You are interested in finding the expected weight of a randomly-selected adult lion:

$$E(W) = E(W|M) \cdot P(M)+E(W|F) \cdot P(F) = (420)\cdot(0.2)+(280)\cdot(0.8) = 308$$

In this case, the entire sample space of adult lions can be divided into two discrete events: picking a male and picking a female.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. How to use it when the sample space is not partitioned?